# Which of Database::<QUERY_TYPE> I should use in Kohana 3.3?

Tags: database, kohana

I need perform query "LOCK TABLE `myTable` WRITE"

```
<?php
$db = Database::instance();
$query = 'LOCK TABLE `myTable` WRITE';
$db->query(Database::WHAT_IS_THE_TYPE_SHOULD_SPECIFY_HERE_?, $query);
```

In framework Kohana 3.3 
file ~/modules/database/classes/Kohana/Database.php
implements folowing types:

const SELECT =  1;
const INSERT =  2;
const UPDATE =  3;
const DELETE =  4;

but none of them fit in my case.
Any idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google works wonders. http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/6401/lockunlock/p1

You can pass NULL as the first argument:

```
$db = Database::instance();
$query = 'LOCK TABLE `myTable` WRITE';
$db->query(NULL, $query);
```

From Kohana: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Database_MySQL#query

```
if ($type === Database::SELECT)
{
    // Return an iterator of results
    return new Database_MySQL_Result($result, $sql, $as_object, $params);
}
elseif ($type === Database::INSERT)
{
    // Return a list of insert id and rows created
    return array(
        mysql_insert_id($this->_connection),
        mysql_affected_rows($this->_connection),
    );
}
else
{
    // Return the number of rows affected
    return mysql_affected_rows($this->_connection);
}
```

As you can see that's why you're able to pass NULL.

Comment: Thanks:) It seems Database::UPDATE and Database::DELETE are not used at all.